# Is there a way to see a history of who has downloaded code base on Github?

Tags: github

I've looked on github, and googled this, but can't find anything. I'd like to see a history of downloads of code on one of our repositories if that is possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Github currently does not support this - at least not exposed to the general public.

You may want to [contacting support](https://help.github.com/contact) to see if they can assist.